# How to replicate modal css3 animation effect when clicking search?

Tags: javascript, css

I really like the effect of clicking on the search box and the search page coming up and the normal page fades out. How can I replicate this? Is this CSS3 only?

https://atmospherejs.com/

Comment: in the link you provided it is CSS3 only with little javascript used for capturing the `click` event -*just like in* @DrinkinPeople *answer*- and it could be done with javascript only as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with CSS only and here is one way.

In this sample I used 2 radio inputs to keep track of whether to show the search box or not.

```css
html, body {  
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#shide, #sshow {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/1024/600/city/9/') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  transition: transform .6s ease-out, opacity .6s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}
  .showsearch{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: #F00;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.searchbox {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
  .searchbox .close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
    .searchbox .close:before,
    .searchbox .close:after {
      content: ' ';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      background: #000;
    }
    .searchbox .close:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
  .searchbox > div {
    position: relative;
    top: 46%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
  }
    .searchbox > div > div {
      font-size: 24px;
    }

#sshow:checked ~ .searchbox {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
#sshow:checked ~ .container {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="search" id="sshow"> 
<input type="radio" name="search" id="shide"> 

<div class="searchbox">
  <label class="close" for="shide"></label>
  <div>
    <div>Search box</div>
    <input type="text" class="field">    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <label class="showsearch" for="sshow">Search</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is css along with a little bit of jquery you can make this happen.  You will need to wrap your body content in a wrapper so you can scale it with css.  Then use jquery toggleClass to give the body a class of something like search-open.  Then you can use transitions for the rest like so:

Here is a fiddle demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/2ssyxu91/)

Css:

```
.search-overlay{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.body-wrapper{
  transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.335, 1.05);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.search-open .search-overlay{
  opacity:1;
  z-index: 5;
}
.search-open .body-wrapper{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0.5;
  transform: scale3d(0.85, 0.85, 1);
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="search-overlay">
     Search Content...
</div>
<div class="body-wrapper">
     Body Content...
 </div>
```

Then jquery to toggle the class use a button or something in the body content and the overlay to close it:

```
$('.search-button, .search-close').on("click", function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("search-open");
});
```

Comment: What issues you put text in the search close div which is just an example for closing the overlay put the text and input in the search overlay wrapper outside of the close div

Comment: Oops, I apologize it is totally my mistake, yeah it is working correctly https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2ssyxu91/2/ , I apologize again, I'll remove my answer for making such a stupid mistake :)

Comment: No problem I probably should use a button instead of a div I was just in a hurry and its less code that way but I can see how it would happen.  I will edit my fiddle so it is a little more clear.

Comment: Yup you'd save up couple DOM elements if you use a button isntead